Why AWS Firewall Manager is FMS?
I understand that FMS stands for Firewall Manager.
However, I can't figure out why it’s abbreviated that way despite searching extensively.
Can anyone explain this?
I also wondered if FMS might stand for an older name like Firewall Management System or Service.
